# How to add datas from one class to another

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a problem and i don't know how to solve it.

I have 2 different classs, and i need to get a datas that are in fist class to another class.

My first class look like :

```
Public Class ZnrEk1Ospos


Private _sif_tvrtka As Integer
Private _sif_radnika As Integer
Private _red_broj As Integer
Private _sif_ovl_osobe As Integer
Private _datum_teorija As Date
Private _datum_praksa As Date
Private _prezime_ime As String
Private _strucna_sprema As String
Private _funkcija As String
Private _status_obrasca As Integer
Private _glavni_instruktor As Integer
Private _instruktor_prezime As String
Private _instruktor_sprema As String
Private _instruktor_funkcija As String
Private _evidencijski_broj As String
Private _potvrda As String

Public Sub New()
    'Do nothing as all private variables has been initiated
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal DataRow As DataRow)
    _sif_tvrtka = CInt(DataRow.Item("sif_tvrtka"))
    _sif_radnika = CInt(DataRow.Item("sif_radnika"))
    _red_broj = CInt(DataRow.Item("red_broj"))
    _sif_ovl_osobe = CInt(DataRow.Item("sif_ovl_osobe"))
    _datum_teorija = IIf(IsDBNull(DataRow.Item("datum_teorija")), Nothing, DataRow.Item("datum_teorija"))
    _datum_praksa = IIf(IsDBNull(DataRow.Item("datum_praksa")), Nothing, DataRow.Item("datum_praksa"))
    _prezime_ime = IIf(IsDBNull(DataRow.Item("prezime_ime")), "", Trim(DataRow.Item("prezime_ime")))
    _strucna_sprema = IIf(IsDBNull(DataRow.Item("strucna_sprema")), "", Trim(DataRow.Item("strucna_sprema")))
    _funkcija = IIf(IsDBNull(DataRow.Item("funkcija")), "", Trim(DataRow.Item("funkcija")))
    _status_obrasca = CInt(DataRow.Item("status_obrasca"))
    _glavni_instruktor = CInt(DataRow.Item("glavni_instruktor"))
    _instruktor_prezime = IIf(IsDBNull(DataRow.Item("instruktor_prezime")), "", Trim(DataRow.Item("instruktor_prezime")))
    _instruktor_sprema = IIf(IsDBNull(DataRow.Item("instruktor_sprema")), "", Trim(DataRow.Item("instruktor_sprema")))
    _instruktor_funkcija = IIf(IsDBNull(DataRow.Item("instruktor_funkcija")), "", Trim(DataRow.Item("instruktor_funkcija")))
    _evidencijski_broj = IIf(IsDBNull(DataRow.Item("evidencijski_broj")), "", Trim(DataRow.Item("evidencijski_broj")))
    _potvrda = IIf(IsDBNull(DataRow.Item("potvrda")), "", Trim(DataRow.Item("potvrda").ToString))
End Sub


Public Property sif_tvrtka() As Integer
    Get
        Return _sif_tvrtka
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _sif_tvrtka = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property sif_radnika() As Integer
    Get
        Return _sif_radnika
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _sif_radnika = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property red_broj() As Integer
    Get
        Return _red_broj
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _red_broj = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property sif_ovl_osobe() As Integer
    Get
        Return _sif_ovl_osobe
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _sif_ovl_osobe = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property datum_teorija() As Date
    Get
        Return _datum_teorija
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Date)
        _datum_teorija = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property datum_praksa() As Date
    Get
        Return _datum_praksa
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Date)
        _datum_praksa = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property prezime_ime() As String
    Get
        Return _prezime_ime
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _prezime_ime = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property strucna_sprema() As String
    Get
        Return _strucna_sprema
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _strucna_sprema = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property funkcija() As String
    Get
        Return _funkcija
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _funkcija = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property status_obrasca() As Integer
    Get
        Return _status_obrasca
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _status_obrasca = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property glavni_instruktor() As Integer
    Get
        Return _glavni_instruktor
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _glavni_instruktor = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property instruktor_prezime() As String
    Get
        Return _instruktor_prezime
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _instruktor_prezime = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property instruktor_sprema() As String
    Get
        Return _instruktor_sprema
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _instruktor_sprema = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property instruktor_funkcija() As String
    Get
        Return _instruktor_funkcija
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _instruktor_funkcija = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property evidencijski_broj() As String
    Get
        Return _evidencijski_broj
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _evidencijski_broj = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property potvrda() As String
    Get
        Return _potvrda
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _potvrda = value
    End Set
End Property
```

And my second class in wich i want go get data from my first class look like:

```
Public Class TempEK1OsposTeorija

Private _sif_ovl_osobe As Integer
Private _datum_teorija As Date
Private _datum_praksa As Date
Private _prezime_ime As String
Private _strucna_sprema As String
```

Now i need to get data in Public Class TempEK1OsposTeorija form class Public Class ZnrEk1Ospos.

Does anybody know how to do that?

Comment: ako ti je odgovor pomogao i prihvati ga ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new instance of that class

```
  Public Class TempEK1OsposTeorija

     Private _sif_ovl_osobe As Integer
     Private _datum_teorija As Date
     Private _datum_praksa As Date
     Private _prezime_ime As String
     Private _strucna_sprema As String

   Public sub PozoviKlasuIvratiPodatke()

'  To use the word using you must implement the IDisposable Interface into first class

      Using cl as new ZnrEk1Ospos

      'get data from first class

      _sif_ovl_osobe  = cl._sif_ovl_osobe 
      _datum_teorija = cl._datum_teorija 
      _datum_praksa = cl._datum_praksa 
      _prezime_ime = cl._prezime_ime 
      _strucna_sprema = cl._strucna_sprema 

      End using 

   End sub
 End class
```